# How to make jQuery loader before server responding for download a file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor, download, loader

I'm french, sorry for my bad english.

I have a slow ASP.NET method who generate a file for me :

```
public ActionResult Method([Bind(Prefix = "Id")] Guid id)
{
    //Long work
    return File(data, "application/pdf", doc.Name + ".pdf");
}
```

And in my cshtml file a button (i use Razor):

```
<a title="Télécharger" onclick="DownloadFile('@entity.Id')"/>
```

And the script method :

```
<script>
    function DownloadFile(id) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("Method", "TheController", new { id = "Id" })'.replace('Id', id);
        $("#divLoading").show();
        $.post(url, null,
        function (data) {
            $("#divLoading").hide();
        });
    }
</script>
```

The divLoading :

```
<div id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px;
    top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #666666; z-index: 30001;
    opacity: .8; filter: alpha(opacity=70);display:none" >
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">
        Génération du document...<img src="../../Content/img/ajax-loader.gif">
    </p>
</div>
```

The C# method is called, the divLoading appear and disappear BUT the file isn't downloaded by navigator.

If i wrote :
    
It's work.
But the loader isn't present. And i want.

My question isn't how to make a loader while donwloading file, but only show the loader before the download starting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that so straight forward because the response is not sent to the browser.

As an alternative you could do 2 requests like that:

```
public ActionResult Method([Bind(Prefix = "Id")] Guid id)
{
    //Long work

    string newGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    TempData[newGuid] = data;

    return Content(newGuid);
}

public ActionResult Download(string guid)
{
    byte[] data = (byte[])TempData[guid];

    return File(data, "application/pdf", "teste.pdf");
}
```

And the script method:

```
function DownloadFile(id) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("Method")';
    $("#divLoading").show();
    $.get(url, 
                function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    $("#divLoading").hide();
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Download")' 
                                            + '?guid=' + data;
                }
           );
}
```

Comment: Okay !
I understand. After any adaptation withmy code, it's work.

Thank you very much and sorry for my bad english again.